# How can I make my computer start an HIIDEN_FILE which fond on my StartUp folder? (python)

Tags: python

I have a file, callde 'example.exe'.
This file, was a python file befor, which I did on it compiling with PyInstaller with thw next row:

```
python pyinstaller.py --onefile --windowed example.py
```

And this row made my 'example.exe' file.

This file I made it to be 'HIDDEN_FILE' with the next row:

```
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetFileAttributesW(u'C:\\Users\\micha\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\example.exe', 0x02)
```

The file is there, but invisible.

When I tried to restart the computer, the file doesnt opened automatically with the computer opening.

Is there any connection between this two things? 
And if it connect. How can I make the computer even though open this file when its HIDDEN_FILE and find on the StartUp folder?

Comment: it shouldn't be a python question.

Comment: I'm not even sure if this should be answered... I mean, doing this stuff seems like trying to prepare poor mans trojan...

Comment: @FilipMalczak I dont see any law that forbids me from learning staff like this ;)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Maybe its related to the way I made it hidden.

Comment: @lkjlkjlkj the only way to know is to do the same thing with only command line tools (no python).

Comment: @FilipMalczak Just for knowledge. Why poor?